# Android: How can I center three Textviews in Tablerow?

Tags: android, textview, tablerow

I have three textview fields in one Tablerow in my TableLayout. 
the first Textview is ***always*** having 50% of the Tablerow, and the other two shares the other 50% of the space.

|-----------Textview 1 ------------|-----Textview 2 & Textview 3------|

|--------------50%-----------------|-------------------50%-----------------|

How to center them all in the middle, something like this:

|-----------------Textview 1 & Textview 2 & Textview 3---------------|

how can I do that ?

ــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــ

**Update:**
Here is my layout

> ```
>     <TableRow
>         android:id="@+id/tableRow25"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:gravity="center"
>         android:orientation="horizontal" >
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/Countdoen_lbl"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:text="Let's wait "
>             android:textColor="#2c3e50"
>             android:textSize="12dp"
>             android:textStyle="italic"
>             android:typeface="serif" >
>         </TextView>
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/Countdown1"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:text=""
>             android:textColor="#e74c3c"
>             android:textSize="12dp"
>             android:textStyle="bold|italic"
>             android:typeface="serif" >
>         </TextView>
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/Countdown2"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:text=" minutes"
>             android:textColor="#2c3e50"
>             android:textSize="12dp"
>             android:textStyle="italic"
>             android:typeface="serif" >
>         </TextView>
>     </TableRow>
> ```

Comment: Can you post your layout code?

Comment: @karvoynistas: question updated, code added ..

Comment: just use a linearlayout with gravity center or center_horizontal, if your tablerow is not inside a tablelayout it will behave like a linearlayout with horizontal orientation

Comment: @TheRedFox: Would you please put you comment as an answer so I can accept it .. thanks

Comment: Could you post the full code that work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Textview 1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Textview 2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Textview 3" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

mention layout_width as "0dp" for all textviews

give layout_weight as "2" for first Textview1

and layout_weight as "1" each for Textview2 & Textview3

and for for acheiving  35% 35% 35% split , with the first and the last Textviews' text aligned to the right and left respectively, and the second Textview's text centralized (please update your question because not all stackoverflow readers will check comments. If you got the answer right, i shall remove the top section describing 50 25 25 layout)

```
   <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="Textview 1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Textview 2" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Textview 3" />
            </TableRow>
```

Comment: if you can post your layout file, i can help you with fixes straight

Comment: Thank you for your answer .. but it is the way around .. what I want for the layout weight is to be 1 for each Textview and all to be centralized in the middle .. It is already seems like they have 2,1,1 as weight and I cannot change it to 1,1,1 !!

Comment: i dont see any weights applied in your layout as in the question.. 

within the 50% 25% 25% areas, you want the text in center, you can use android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 

but to achieve 50% 25% 25% split, you have to use layout_weight as 2 1 1 and widht as 0dp for all textviews

Comment: I don't want to "achieve 50% 25% 25% split" .. I want to achieve 35% 35% 35% split , with the first and the last Textviews' text aligned to the right and left respectively, and the second Textview's text centralized. I've applied Layout weight but still having the same issue

Comment: use android:gravity="center_horizontal" for textview1
android:gravity="right" and android:gravity="left"

note that you have to use gravity (not layout_gravity) to handle alignment of contents inside a view.

also to get 33.33% for all 3, you have to mention width as 0 and weight as 1 for all three

Comment: check the layout in my answer to acheive 35% 35% 35% split , with the first and the last Textviews' text aligned to the right and left respectively, and the second Textview's text centralized

Comment: Please update the question to avoid confusion among stackoverflow users

Answer (score 0):

just use a linearlayout with gravity center or center_horizontal, if your tablerow is not inside a tablelayout it will behave like a linearlayout with horizontal orientation